# Top message says 1 more response available, but linked page says out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed

I see the prompt at the top (nice).

But when I click through:

maximum of 90 days allowed

Comment: Couldn't you find it in either of your 4 questions or your single answer?

Comment: @perbet, though confusing (and too much ranting) you have more info on this issue here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65218/one-reason-why-i-hate-the-current-non-e-mail-notification-system

Comment: this is now completed; see my edited response

Comment: @Jeff fixed indeed! Looking much better! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just upvoted this question after the same thing happened to me. I just logged into ServerFault for the first time in a long time to see the message "You have 1 new response." I click it, nothing. I click through the date-spans, nothing. Well, what is the response?

Is it too tasking on the database to request the x-most-recent responses to show on that page? Fortunately for me, I only have a few questions, so I can manually scrub through and find the newest response. But if I have 10 questions, 20 questions, or 50 questions, this scrub-time becomes very tiresome.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's not optimal, but this is by design at the moment; if we don't limit the query dates, the queries will time out.

edit: This is now complete.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/

Comment: If the link isn't going to do what it suggests it does, then I, as a user, should not be presented that link.  Your data structures obviously can detect new comments already, so can you simply annotate that structure to record the date of the last comment, and then not present the link if it is > 90 days?

Comment: It's idiotic behavior to have a popup bar that notifies a user that information is available when the information is unavailable.  Fine. Limit the query dates if needed.  But be consistent and limit the range the popup bar code considers as well.  And if you can't do that, give any information that you can display by altering the range to 90 days.  If someone has been away for 90+ days, do you really want to add a reason for never coming back?

Comment: Why not just limit 90 days but add a "previous 90 days" link?