# Responses report doesn't work when you've been away too long

Tags: bug, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top message says 1 more response available, but linked page says out of date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26447/top-message-says-1-more-response-available-but-linked-page-says-out-of-date)

So I haven't used StackOverflow for many months and I log in to see what's been going on.  I have a ton of answers and comments so the little popup bar on the top of the page says "You have $n new comments.  See your responses."  When I click the link (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/1438/2009-07-07/2010-02-18?tab=responses), it very unhelpfully notifies me that "maximum of 90 days allowed".

So either:

1. Fix the responses page to show more than 90 days.
   or:
2. Fix the popup to ignore responses that are older than 90 days since they aren't discoverable anymore.
   or:
3. Fix the responses page to show what it can even if part of the date range is out of range.

Basically, it's probably not a good idea to annoy lapsed users who are just now getting back to the site.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26447/top-message-says-1-more-response-available-but-linked-page-says-out-of-date

Comment: Saw that.  I don't yet have the reputation here to change the question, which doesn't not explore the implications of the design decisions.  It didn't seem right to rephrase the question in an answer, so I started fresh.

Comment: I should have said "possible duplicate" and as this suggests possible solutions I haven't voted to close - nor will I.