# It says I have a new response, but the link doesn't show any

Tags: bug, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Responses report doesn’t work when you’ve been away too long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39845/responses-report-doesnt-work-when-youve-been-away-too-long)

I've returned to stackoverflow after a while and the line at the top said to me that I have a new response. I followed that link and the other page said I have no responses at all. But I did ask questions and I did get responses already! Where are they? I've noticed the time range selectors but "last month" is not far enough. Manipulating the dates in the URL fails.

Comment: could you provide link to your question or answer?

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39845/responses-report-doesnt-work-when-youve-been-away-too-long