# See your responses date flaw

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, recent-activity, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top message says 1 more response available, but linked page says out of date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26447/top-message-says-1-more-response-available-but-linked-page-says-out-of-date)

If get a "You have 3 new answers; 1 new comment. See your responses." on stackoverflow, however system does not allow the date range:

2009-11-20 00:00:00Z to 2010-07-15 23:59:59Z

maximum of 90 days allowed

So for people who have no used account in a while they won't be able to see the new responses.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably like that [by-design] to reduce strain on the database and page load times. **A LOT** of results could be returned for users who use the site daily if they specified more than 90 days.

Just specify 90-day spans from the date of your last visit until you reach today.