# After 60 day absence, comments link took me to error page

Tags: bug, notification-bar, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top message says 1 more response available, but linked page says out of date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26447/top-message-says-1-more-response-available-but-linked-page-says-out-of-date)

I haven't visited the photography site for more than 60 days (shame on me) because I'm travelling.

The banner at the top suggested I view a new comment on one of my responses. Clicking the link took me to a confusing error page. (Confusing because it complained about a 60 range I hadn't explicitly chosen.)

This is the URL and you can see it was generated with an invalid range:

```
http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/users/recent/190/2010-08-19/2011-01-19?tab=responses
```

Comment: More recent reports are [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70309/envelope-gives-error-message-if-you-havent-logged-in-for-61-days) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65218/one-reason-why-i-hate-the-current-non-e-mail-notification-system), but [this has been a longstanding issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26447/top-message-says-1-more-response-available-but-linked-page-says-out-of-date). Status is "deferred", so it's something that may be looked at.

Comment: The `/recent` page no longer exists; voting to delete rather than trying to reopen and reclose as too localized.